# How import a SQL file to Wordpress Posts (Post Title and Body)

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, import

I have acquired a Facts database that has thousands of Facts.  It's a SQL file that has one table I believe.

How would I import into a Wordpress site as separate Posts (title and body)?

I'm not a programmer so I'd need some direction.

Thanks!

Comment: How about a little extract from the sql script? I assume your wordpress blog runs on mySQL, from what source is the script?

Comment: Yes, Wordpress runs on SQL.  The source was from http://mydatamaster.com/2007/09/03/free-database-of-random-facts-available-over-2000-entries/

Answer (score 0):

So, based on the link you added in the comment you should be able to run the sql script on your database which will then create a facts table. From there you then have to write a sql script that creates a blog entry for every fact in the fact database.

Comment: Yes, that is the task that needs to happen.  That is exactly what I need assistance with  :)

Comment: So have you been able to run the script on your database and create the facts table? Do you have access to the database with phpmyadmin or something similar?